# Django allauth, How to make page redirect to homepage

Tags: django-allauth

How do I make my Django allauth to redirect me to home page instead of
127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile

I want it to just redirect to 127.0.0.1:8000 after pressing the login/sign up button

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes to your project level settings.py file. Add the code below. You can also use the name of your view you specified in the specific app.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```